# PHP / mySQL - for loop doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have these lines of code:

```
$user = $_SESSION['name'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_shop");
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE `user` = '$user' AND `done` = '0'");

while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql ) ){

    $file = $result['items'];
    $res = explode(",",$file);
    $total = 0;
    $tmp = count( $res );
    for( $i = 0 ; $i <= $tmp; $i++ ){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_details` WHERE `file_name` = '".$res[$i]."'";
        echo $sql;
        $sql = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM `tbl_details` WHERE `file_name` = '".$res[$i]."'");
        while( $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql ) ){
            $total += $res['price'];
        }
        echo "<script>alert('$total');</script>";
    }
}
```

where `$res[1]` must contain a value of `1000` from my database, but it just gives me a `null` value.

As you can see I tried to `echo` out `$sql`, `$res[0]` returned the right one but `$res[1]` returned:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_details` WHERE `file_name` = ''
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: what is your `echo $sql;` outputs?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `tbl_details` WHERE `file_name` = '1.jpg'SELECT * FROM `tbl_details` WHERE `file_name` = ''SELECT * FROM `tbl_details` WHERE `file_name` = ''

this is the output

Comment: i think the looping is right my only problem is why my $res[1] returns nothing

Comment: If you were to add `print_r($res);` immediately after `$res = explode(",",$file);` what would you get in the array? Does this contain all the values you would expect?

Comment: yep it returns just what i expect. Array ( [0] => 1.jpg [1] => 10.jpg )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder whether it is because the inner sql statement references the same variable name `$sql`? Changed the inner variable names ....

```
$user = $_SESSION['name'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_shop");
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE `user` = '$user' AND `done` = '0'");

while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql ) ){

    $file = $result['items'];
    $res = explode(",",$file);
    $total = 0;
    $tmp = count( $res );

    for( $i = 0 ; $i < $tmp; $i++ ){

        $sql_inner = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_details` WHERE `file_name` = '".$res[$i]."'";
        #echo $sql_inner;

        $res_inner = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM `tbl_details` WHERE `file_name` = '".$res[$i]."'");
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $res_inner ) ){
            $total += $row->price;
        }
        echo "<script>alert('$total');</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude it worked like a miracle . :D

thanks ^-^v i almost died here . xD

Comment: since you commented `echo $sql_inner;` you can comment `echo "<script>alert('$total');</script>";` as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should change `$i <= $tmp` to `$i < $tmp`.

Because [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) `$tmp = count( $res );` returns number of elements but not the max index of element.

```
for( $i = 0 ; $i < $tmp; $i++ ){
```

and here you should use another variable name not `$res`:

```
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql ) ){
        $total += $row['price'];
    }
```

Comment: tried it tho, didn't worked for me. 

$res[1] still returns nothing.

Comment: @YesSir you repeat `$res[1]` so many time in comments, but I don't see any code line that outputs that `$res[1]` somewhere in your code  provided.